# Ember-cli unit test using ember-cli-simple-auth

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to write a `unit test` for a controller that uses `simple-auth authentication` in an `ajax` call. Assertion tests work great but the `session` property does not appear to be defined in the `unit test` module scope.

Example action in controller:

```
authenticate() {
  let credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
  this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:token', credentials)
    .then(() => {
      this.transitionToRoute('index');
    }, (error) => {
      this.set('errorMessage', error.error);
    });
}
```

Example test:

```
it('should not authenticate', function () {
  let controller = this.subject();
  controller.send('authenticate');
  expect(controller.get('errorMessage')).to.equal("Invalid email/password combination");
});
```

Session is undefined error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined
at authenticate (http://localhost:7357/assets/app.js:587:28)
at mixin.Mixin.create.send (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:37164:54)
at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/assets/app.js:2002:18)
at Context.wrapper (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1756:27)
at invoke (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:13772:21)
at Context.suite.on.context.it.context.specify.method (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:13837:13)
at Test.require.register.Runnable.run (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7064:15)
at Runner.require.register.Runner.runTest (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7493:10)
at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7571:12
at next (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7418:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests you don't have a running application so injections etc. that happen in initializers aren't run. The best way to make sure the session exists in the controller would be to stub it which would also make it easy to make sure it behaves as you want it to behave in your test.

The alternative would be to turn the unit test into an acceptance test - in that case you have an initialized app that the test runs with and the session will be available in the controller already.